# Is there a nameof() operator for MVC controllers in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The newly introduced [`nameof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) operator is useful in making my code my "typed".

Instead of

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit");
```

we can write

```
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Edit));
```

But for to get a controller's name is not that straightforward, because we have a `Controller` suffix. Just want to know if I want to have a

```
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), controllernameof(Home));
```

to take the place of

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

how can we implement the `controllernameof` operator?

Comment: No! There's no such operator exist. You have write your custom name parser to get name of controller.

Comment: `nameof(IndexController).Replace("Controller","")` - or something more robust if you have a `RemoteControllerController` class (which MVC may choke on anyways)

Comment: @DStanley I think you meant `nameof(IndexController).Replace("Controller", "")`

Comment: @DStanley What if there's a controller named `FlightControllerController`? ;)

Comment: @juharr Thanks, Fixed.

Comment: you can write your own method for that and reuse it every where

Comment: As far as I remember 'Controller' suffix is just a convention which can be customized.

Comment: See also this (closed) issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5853

Answer (score 10):

Maybe an extension method like the following would suit your needs:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
  public static string ControllerName(this Type controllerType)
  {
     Type baseType = typeof(Controller);
     if (baseType.IsAssignableFrom(controllerType))
     {
        int lastControllerIndex = controllerType.Name.LastIndexOf("Controller");
        if (lastControllerIndex > 0)
        {
           return controllerType.Name.Substring(0, lastControllerIndex);
        }
     }

     return controllerType.Name;
  }
}
```

Which you could invoke like so:

```
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), typeof(HomeController).ControllerName());
```

Comment: Well, this method will be called each time route is requested. `nameof` operator is somewhat better concerning performance as it works at compile-time.

Comment: Very good point, @voroninp.  Perhaps an extension method that just takes the string result of `nameof(ControllerName)` would be more efficient - though even use of extensions at all might not be fully performant.

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no such possibility. You might be intertested to use [`T4MVC`](https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC) instead.

> `T4MVC`- a T4 template for `ASP.NET MVC` apps that creates strongly typed helpers that eliminate the use of literal strings in many places.
>
> e.g. instead of
>
> ```
> @Html.ActionLink("Dinner Details", "Details", "Dinners", new { id = Model.DinnerID }, null)
> ```
>
> `T4MVC` lets you write
>
> ```
> @Html.ActionLink("Dinner Details", MVC.Dinners.Details(Model.DinnerID))
> ```

Answer (score 8):

Totally understand your desire to not use magic strings! Between the comments above and [this article](https://daveaglick.com/posts/using-expression-trees-to-get-class-and-member-names). I've started using the following in a base controller which my other controllers inherit from:

```
public RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction<TController>(Expression<Func<TController, string>> expression, object routeValues)
{
    if (!(expression.Body is ConstantExpression constant))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Expression must be a constant expression.");
    }

    string controllerName = typeof(TController).Name;

    controllerName = controllerName.Substring(0, controllerName.LastIndexOf("Controller"));

    return RedirectToAction(constant.Value.ToString(), controllerName, routeValues);
}

public RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction<TController>(Expression<Func<TController, string>> expression)
{
    return RedirectToAction(expression, null);
}
```

I then use :

```
 return RedirectToAction<HomeController>(a => nameof(a.Index));
```

and

```
 return RedirectToAction<HomeController>(a => nameof(a.Index), new { text= "searchtext" });
```

Answer (score 5):

The solution that solves the case of the XControllerController would look more like:

```
String nameStr = nameof(FlightControllerController);
nameStr = nameStr.Substring(0, nameStr.LastIndexOf("Controller"));
```

Answer (score 5):

In C# 8 and later you can use the range operator to remove the last 10 chars:

```
nameof(AccountController)[..^10]
```

The 10 can be replaced with a constant, if you’re not into the whole brevity thing.

Comment: nice tip! it's a simple way to solve it

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Jon Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9518354/jon-ryan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54746006):

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction<T>(string ActionName, object routeValues) where T : BaseController
    {
        string controllerName = typeof(T).Name;
        controllerName = controllerName.Substring(0, controllerName.LastIndexOf("Controller"));
        return RedirectToAction(ActionName, controllerName, routeValues);
    }
    
    public RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction<T>(string ActionName) where T : BaseController
    {
        return RedirectToAction<T>(ActionName, null);
    }
}
```

Used like so:

```
return RedirectToAction<AccountController>(nameof(AccountController.Login));
return RedirectToAction<AccountController>(nameof(AccountController.Login), new { text= "searchtext" });
```

---

Extension for razor page:

```
public static string ControllerName(this string controllerName)
{
    return controllerName.Substring(0, controllerName.LastIndexOf("Controller"));
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
nameof(AccountController).ControllerName()
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this kind of thing, I took @stephen.vakil's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36626343/2374053), merged with @huysentruitw's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44108646/2374053) and wrote this:

```
namespace Helpers
{
    public static class ControllerHelper
    {
        public static string Nameof<TController>() where TController : Controller
        {
            var name = typeof(TController).Name;

            var indexOfControllerText = name.LastIndexOf("Controller");
            if (indexOfControllerText > 0)
            {
                return name.Substring(0, indexOfControllerText);
            }

            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

To use this, first you have to add "using static"

```
using static Helpers.ControllerHelper;
```

And then use it in the code like this

```
var controllerName = Nameof<TestController>();
```

Comment: How to get Action Name in a controller? Like var actionName = Nameof<TestAction>(TestController);

Comment: @HassanGulzar, no. It's only for controller. Maybe you can use this and create an helper class: 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18248594/2374053

But, if you are just looking name of an action without instance, then you can use this usage:

nameof(TestController.Index)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@Trương Quốc Khánh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63832800/7335274) answer, I've modified the extension method by adding some checks:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ControllerName(this string controllerName)
    {
        if (!controllerName.EndsWith("Controller") || controllerName == "Controller")
            throw new ArgumentException($"{controllerName} is not a valid name for a Controller class");

        return controllerName.Substring(0, controllerName.LastIndexOf("Controller"));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
nameof(Controller).ControllerName()
```